# criar rotas com react-router-dom

Tags: react, react-router-dom

A situação é a seguinte, estou usando o react-router-dom numa app em ReactJS, estou aprendendo a usar o ReactJS. Então eu crie duas rotas 'Logon' e 'Welcome', porem toda vez que uso react-router-dom eu não consigo visualizar minhas rotas, a unica coisa que consigo visualizar no http//:localhost:3000 é o "background: #f0f0f5; que criei no global.css" , parece que as rotas não existem. Então eu queria uma ajuda para entender porque o React  não está  mostrando as pages do meu app no http//:localhost:3000  quando eu uso react-router-dom?

o código:

**Logon**
É algo simples apenas para  aprender a criar rotas.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FiLogIn } from 'react-icons/fi';
export default function Logon(){
    return (
      
         <div>
          <form>faça se cadastro</form>
          <input placeholder= "seu id" />
          <button type="submit">Entrar</button>

          <a href="/Register">
              <FiLogIn size={16} color= "#e02041" />
              não tenho cadastro
          </a>
      
          </div>
     
    );
}
```

**Routes.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
 
import Logon from './pages/Logon';
import Welcome from './pages/Welcome';

export default function  Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path= "/"  exact componemt= {Logon} />
            <Route path= "/Welcome"   componemt= {Welcome} />
            
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './Routes';
import './global.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes/>
    
   );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**nota:**
possíveis erros abaixo quando eu instalei o react-router-dom.

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 
3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev 
|| >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Você colocou a propriedade ```exact``` de forma incorreta na rota raiz ```/```, você escreveu ```exect```, se corrigindo isso ainda não aparecer a página, adicione o exemplo da sua página Logon.

Comment: @Daniel Mendes, corrigido mas não mudou nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo, pois seu **Routes.js** está com uma sintaxe incorreta na tag `<Route>`.

A sua rota está sendo definida da seguinte forma:

```
<Route path= "/"  exact componemt= {Logon} />
<Route path= "/Welcome"   componemt= {Welcome} />
```

Perceba que a propriedade `component` está escrita de forma incorreta: *componemt*

---

Basta corrigir o nome da propriedade para `component` e com isso sua página será exibida:

```
<Route path= "/"  exact component= {Logon} />
<Route path= "/Welcome"   component= {Welcome} />
```

Comment: Como! eu escrevi todas as propriedades no **Routes.js** de forma errada e o React não mostrou erro!? @Daniel Mendes muito obrigado cara, eu preciso de óculos mesmo.

Comment: A exact eu encontrei logo de cara, a do component eu realmente demorei pra encontrar... :D

Comment: perfeito cara, muito obrigado, esta funcionado certinho agora.